# MassTransit - PublishFault stops working when Message Q is down

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am connecting a publish observer, using the code below (and RabbitMQ). When RabbitMQ is running, it works well - I can see the console messages on PostPublish and PrePublish.

However, when i stop RabbitMQ, and publish, the PublishFault works once, but never again whilst RabbitMQ remains stopped.

I am attempting to persist a message to another datastore (and log and error), in the event of a publish failing - I thought that the PublishFault method would be the best place to do this. This doesn't really work if only the first failure is detected.

Is this behaviour expected? Is there a better way to achieve failed message persistance.

PS...as soon as I start RabbitMQ again, I then see all my PrePublish and PostPublish debug messages , for my failed messages. Which, I assume, is to be expected.

```cs
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Pipeline;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Mtt.Publisher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IBusControl busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
            {
                var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("user");
                    h.Password("pass");
                });

                sbc.UseRetry(Retry.Immediate(5));
            });

            busControl.Start();
            busControl.ConnectPublishObserver(new PublishObserver());

            var input = "";

            while (input != "exit")
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                busControl.Publish<Test>(new TestMessage());
            }

            busControl.Stop();
        }
    }

    public interface Test { }
    public class TestMessage : Test { }

    public class PublishObserver : IPublishObserver
    {
        public async Task PostPublish<T>(MassTransit.PublishContext<T> context) where T : class
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- POST PUBLISH ----");
        }


        public async Task PrePublish<T>(MassTransit.PublishContext<T> context) where T : class
        {
            Console.WriteLine("**** PRE PUBLISH ****");
        }


        public async Task PublishFault<T>(MassTransit.PublishContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
        {
            Console.WriteLine("%%%%%% EXCEPTION %%%%%%%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will look at this and verify.

Comment: Confirmed, the publish faults stop until the connection is restored. Will continue to investigate. Issue entered: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/473

Comment: Issue fixed, thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris. It looks like a similar issue exists with ISendEndpoint.Send; we are seeing the same incorrect behavior where the SendObserver is only invoked on the first exception when RabbitMQ is an inaccessible state. Substituting this with IBus.Publish and a PublishObserver works as expected. MassTransit v3.3.5, RabbitMQ 3.6.4.

Comment: GitHub issue entered: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/631.